# What kind of algorithm does .htpasswd uses?

Tags: encryption, hash, htpasswd, cryptography, .htpasswd

I am trying to generate this kind of hashes programmatically:

```
axF3s9cdEnsNP
```

But I can't identify what kind of hash it is. The hash comes from a .htpasswd file.

All the online htpasswd generators I tried generates different type of hashes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's CRYPT encryption - an old default. You should probably use MD5 or SHA instead - see `man htpasswd` for more information.

How are you trying to generate your passwords? You could run `htpasswd -n -b username password`, but most languages probably have a library function for that already.

Perl example:

```
perl -e 'print crypt("passwordgoeshere","salt") . "\n"'
```

The second parameter is the salt. As Gerard points out it's better to use a random string as salt.

Comment: This is *REALLY* insecure. Part of your unencrypted password will show up in the returned digest (in this case it's the "pa" in "papAq5PwY/QQM"). You should use random characters instead: http://dev.perl.org/perl6/rfc/208.html